# iOS - Will application get crash after writing UI updation code on background thread

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uikit

If I write accidentally UI updating code on a background thread after fetching data from network req. So Will my application get crash?

Answer (score 0):

From apple docs:

> Updating UI on a thread other than the main thread is a common mistake that can result in missed UI updates, visual defects, data corruptions, and crashes. [source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/code_diagnostics/main_thread_checker)

So it *can* crash, but it can also not crash. It might update the UI or it might not. It might crash immediately when the code is called; it might crash in the next runloop, or it might crash minutes later.  It might cause weird UI that make you say WTF. In short, its behavior is undefined. Which makes can make it a really hard bug to track down and fix.

If you are asking what is the exact behavior to expect when doing this. The answer is: in a debug environment you should expect the Main Thread Checker to catch it and cause a crash with a good crash report.  If it is a production build you can expect some crashes that look like this: [Application crashes very rarely with UI update on secondary thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16714648/application-crashes-very-rarely-with-ui-update-on-secondary-thread), but they might look different.  If you have a small user base you might not see any crashes, but still have a very buggy app.

Answer (score -1):

**Straight Answer : Your Application Won't crash.**

UI Update must be done in Main thread

Apple Documentation:

> DispatchQueue manages the execution of work items. Each work item
>   submitted to a queue is processed on a pool of threads managed by the
>   system.

So, use

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //your UI code
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Why do you want to update UI in the background thread ? it's a bad practice.
You'll get something like this:
[image]

Comment: Why did some people vote that my answer isn't useful ? i just showing for him what'll happen in case of updating the UI in background thread !